# Concat 1 to n items into new spark column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I try to have a dynamic concat of fields, based on some configuration settings the goal is to have a new fields with merged values of 1 to n fields.

```
language = "JP;EN"
language = list(str(item) for item in language.split(";"))
no_langs = len(language)

# check if columns for multi-language exists
for lang in language:
   doc_lang = "doctor.name_" + lang
   if doc_lang not in case_df.columns:
      case_df_final = AddColumn(case_df, doc_lang)

### combine translations of masterdata
case_df = case_df.withColumn(
   "doctor",
    F.concat(
       F.col(("doctor.name_" + language[0])),
       F.lit(" // "),
       F.col(("doctor.name_" + language[1])),
  ),
)
```

What I would like to achieve is that the new column is dynamic depending of the amount of languages configured. E.g. If only one language is used the result would be like this.

```
case_df = case_df.withColumn(
   "doctor",
    F.col(("doctor.name_" + lang[0]))
)
```

For 2 languages or more it should pick all the languages based on the order in the list.
Thanks for your help.
I am using Spark 2.4. with Python 3

The expected output would be the following

[image]

Comment: spark version ?

Comment: @Srinivas Spark 2.4 with Python3

Comment: expected output ?

Comment: @Srinivas I added a picture which shows the expected output for 3 configured languages if only 1 language is configures it would be only e.g. Japanese_name

Comment: you can use `concat_ws()`. It accepts a delimiter which in your case is `'\\'` and will concatenate subsequent column values delimited by that character. In case of a `null`, the field is skipped. Meaning, if you have one language then it will not use the delimiter at all. e.g. - `concate_ws('//', 'doctor.name_jp', 'doctor.name_en', 'doctor.name_de')` will generate your expected output.

Comment: @samkart thanks for the hint but how would I create a dynamic element for the section depending on the configuration? ``concate_ws('//', "dynamic column list")``

Comment: @TobiasBruckert you can use list comprehension for that, just unpack it within the `concat_ws()`. but could you please explain the configuration that you're talking about? does this config apply to all rows or a subset of them? how do you plan on using that?

Comment: @samkart I am running the code with different parameters which I pass into the script e.g. ``language = "JP;EN" so in that case I expect a combined field like ``case_df = case_df.withColumn("doctor", F.concate_ws('//', 'doctor.name_jp', 'doctor.name_en')) if the parameters change the new column would contain other languages.

Comment: @TobiasBruckert yes, this can be done using list comprehension. `list(map(lambda k: 'doctor.name_'+k.lower(), list_of_langs))` will generate the list that can be passed to `concat_ws()`.

Comment: @samkart thanks for the hint but I think I am missing something when I execute the following code ```doc_fields = list(map(lambda k: 'doctor.name_'+k, language))
print(doc_fields)
case_df = case_df.withColumn("doctor", F.concat_ws('//', doc_fields)) ``` than I get the error: TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: ['doctor.name_JP', 'doctor.name_EN'] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Comment: @TobiasBruckert `concat_ws()` does not accept lists. you'll need to unpack it as stated in my comment above. use the `*` unpacker, e.g. - `*doc_fields`

Comment: @samkart I get a stranger error following your suggestion. ```Fail to execute: case_df = case_df.withColumn("doctor", F.concat_ws('//', *doc_fields))
Traceback: "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco return f(*a, **kw) File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value format(target_id, ".", name), value) py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error calling o310.withColumn: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`doctor.name_JP`' given input columns: [... doctor.name_EN, doctor.name_JP ...];```

Comment: @TobiasBruckert you could debug that by using the column names instead of the list as a first pass to test the output. I'm inclined towards wrapping the column names in `col()` to make it explicit that the name is from a struct column. currently it is searching for `doctor.name_JP` as a whole column name, not `doctor` struct's `name_JP` field. But try debugging it yourself for starters -- __this discussion is just going on and on__ -- for more help read through the documentation provided for the spark and sql functions, very helpful

Comment: @samkart the actual column is not a structs field, it is actually column name with a dot. When I rename the columns first ```for lang in language: doc_lang_new = doc_lang.replace(".","_")
case_df = case_df.withColumnRenamed(doc_lang, doc_lang_new)
case_df = case_df.withColumn("doctor", F.concat_ws('//', *doc_fields))``` than the concat_ws runs. Any idea how I resolve it without the rename?

Comment: @TobiasBruckert does `col('doctor.name_JP')` not work in your case?

Comment: @samkart for some reason not.. I tried ```doc_fields = list(map(lambda k: F.col("doctor.name_"+ k), language))
case_df = case_df.withColumn("doctor", F.concat_ws('//', *doc_fields))``` and get the follwing error ```py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1017.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`doctor.name_JP`' given input columns: [..., doctor.name_JP, doctor.name_EN, ....];;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final working code is the following:

```
# check if columns for multi-language exists
for lang in language:
    doc_lang = "doctor.name_" + lang
    if doc_lang not in case_df.columns:
        case_df = AddColumn(case_df, doc_lang)
    doc_lang_new = doc_lang.replace(".", "_")
    case_df = case_df.withColumnRenamed(doc_lang, doc_lang_new)

doc_fields = list(map(lambda k: "doctor_name_" + k, language))
case_df = case_df.withColumn("doctor", F.concat_ws(" // ", *doc_fields))
```

Thanks all for the help and hints.